# cannot open desire page through cucumber

Tags: webdriver, cucumber

i am new to cucumber. i am facing one problem which i tried my best to solve but i did not fix it.
the problem is how to connect cucumber to specific web page on google chrome.
the below is code

```
"

import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MyStepdefsss {
   public WebDriver driver;
    @Given("^go to desire web page$")
    public void go_to_desire_web_page() throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver" , "C:\\Users\\muhammad.ilyas\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55vJUqHSbkQ");

    }
"
```

when i run the above code which is mention in picture it give me result like
[google chrome open and not proceeding to the required page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMFaa.png)

[Here is code snipshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqAhg.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that your Desktop Chrome version is not compatible with the ChromeDriver. Are you sure you are using the latest ChromeDriver.exe.

Look for the latest [**here**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) or upgrade your chrome browser version. Or you may be try degrading the ChromeDriver version to 2.7 or earlier in case you are already on latest.

Make sure to delete the existing ChromeDriver from the path or change the name.